# Iterate through std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, initializer-list, parameter-pack

```
//parameter pack sum example

constexpr int sum(int N= 0)
{
    return N;
}
template<typename ...Args>
constexpr int sum(int first, int second, Args ...N)
{
    return first + second + sum(N...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sum<int>(1,6,3);
}
```

Is it possible to make this sum at compile time with `std::initializer_list<int>` how can i iterate recursive through this.

Comment: You don't have `std::initializer_list<int>` here.

Comment: Are you really limited to C++11, (un)folding pack syntax has been improved a lot in later revisions.

Comment: For compile time, you also requires `constexpr` (and later revision of standard allows also to write them easier).

Comment: Can you explain more detailed what is the difference between parameter_pack and std::initializer_list ? Which are the used cases for each?

Comment: `template<typename ...Args>` is parameter pack, `std::initializer_list<T>` is ...initializer_list ;). Call changes from `sum_pack(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` to `sum_ini({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})`. parameter pack allows non homogeneous types so `template <typename...Ts> void print(const Ts&...); print(42, "Hi", 5.3);`

Answer (score 7):

`sum` with `std::initializer_list` might be done the following way in C++11:

```
template <typename It>
constexpr int sum(It it, It end)
{
    return it == end ? 0 : (*it + sum(it + 1, end));
}

constexpr int sum(std::initializer_list<int> ini)
{
    return sum(ini.begin(), ini.end());
}

static_assert(sum({1, 2, 3, 4, 5})== 15, "!");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd0fe3897f2af899)

C++14 allows loop in `constexpr` function allowing to get rid of recursion:

```
constexpr int sum(std::initializer_list<int> ini)
{
    int res = 0;
    for (int e : ini) {
        res += e;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And in C++20, `std::accumulate` is marked as constexpr, allowing

```
constexpr int sum(std::initializer_list<int> ini)
{
    return accumulate(ini.begin(), ini.end(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since C++20, you can use [`std::reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reduce) as it is marked `constexpr`:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <numeric>

constexpr int sum(std::initializer_list<int> init) {
   return std::reduce(init.begin(), init.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution doing the same more purely without initializer list and constexpr. Works with with gcc-4.4 which has partial C++11 support:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int N, int ...Args>
struct SumImpl
{
  enum { RESULT = N + SumImpl<Args...>::RESULT };
};

template<>
struct SumImpl<0>
{
  enum { RESULT = 0 };
};

template<int ...Args>
struct Sum
{
  enum { RESULT = SumImpl<Args..., 0>::RESULT };
};

int main()
{
  std::cout << Sum<1,6,0,3,23>::RESULT << "\n";
}
```